# Deleting all Kafka topics using kafka-topics.sh

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to delete all Kafka topics at once using the Kafka-topics.sh command-line tool. I've come across the --delete flag, but I'm unsure about the syntax and usage. Can someone please guide me on the correct command to achieve this? I understand that I need to use a regular expression pattern for this purpose. Any precautions or considerations I should be aware of when using this command?

I'm using Kafka version 2.12-3.5.0 and I have a ZooKeeper server running at localhost:2181 and kafka server on 9092.

Comment: What options have you tried? The worst that'll happen is that it'll tell you the syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this command it will delete all topics in your Kafka.

./bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --topic '.*'

Comment: Thank you it worked. I just needed a command for the Mac terminal that can delete all Kafka topics using kafka-topics.sh.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AdminClient to get the list of the all the topics and then run the loop to delete them.

Some thing like this:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);

AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props);

Map<String, List<PartitionInfo>> topics = consumer.listTopics();

for( Map.Entry<String, List<PartitionInfo>> val : topics.entrySet()){
    adminClient.deleteTopics(val.getKey());
}
```

If there is a pattern in your topic name , you can use regex in command line to delete them.

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-servers localhost:9092 --delete --topic 'topic-.*'
```

UPDATE 1 :

As per @OneCricketeer suggestion, using AdminClient

```
    Set<String> tops = adminClient.listTopics().names().get();
    
    for (String topicsToDelete : tops) {
        adminClient.deleteTopics(Collections.singleton(topicsToDelete));
    }
```

Comment: AdminClient can list topics too. Shouldn't need a consumer